# how to test in-app purchase using test account in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I already created a sample code for in-app purchase for iPhone application, but now i want to know how to test in-app purchase using test account.

Thanks and Regards,
ranganathpavan.

Answer (score 0):

- on iTunes connect create a test user
- on the device you are going to be testing on make sure you log out of the app store (this is important), when you come to test making the purchase use the test account you just created
- if you haven't created an app entry on iTunes connect then do so
- create some test products, don't upload an image, leave their status as awaiting image - this is also important, this is the correct way to create test products according to Apple.

When you perform the purchase as you will be using the test user on the device it will act as if a real purchase was made but no billing etc. is performed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created app and added in-app purchase in iTunesConeect, you can create test user by clicking on 'Manage Users' section.

- Select 'Manage Users'
- Click on 'Test User'
- 'Add new user'
- Fill with necessary details and submit.